# Cannot open root site with System Account in SPD

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, system-account

I cannot open root site with System Account in SPD. Rest all sub-sites are opening with System Account. When I enter credentials of System Account in SPD to open root site, the credentials window pop-up appears repeatedly.

Comment: Is the system account set as a site collection admin? Try logging in with a site collection admin account.

Comment: Yes the System Account is site collection admin. This behavior I am just recently facing otherwise everything was working fine until yesterday.

Comment: You say it was working fine the day before.  To the best of your knowledge, has anything changed at all with SharePoint and/or the underlying infrastructure?  Can you open the site by logging in using the SharePoint Farm account?